# Find and compare input value with JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to compare user input value with JSON data.

I found some questions similar to this one, but it didn't solve my problem.

This is my code, do you know why it doesn't work.

Javascript

```
fetch('js/countries.json') 
.then(res => res.json())   
.then(data => { 

  function checkCountry() {
    let input = document.getElementById("countryInput").value;
    let country = data.find(check => check.country === "Norway");
    let text;

    if (input === data[country]) {
      text = "Yes";

    } else {
      text = "No";
    }
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = text;
  }

  document.getElementById("check").addEventListener("click", checkCountry);

  console.log(data);
})
```

JSON

```
[{"country":"USA","active":true},
{"country":"Spain","active":true},
{"country":"Norway","active":true}]
```

HTML

```
<form action="">
 <div class="input-container">
  <input id="countryInput" type="text" placeholder="Country">
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
 </div>  
  <button id="check" type="button">CHECK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you post also the html please?

Comment: HTML added @Kurohige

Comment: What it doesn't work?

Comment: How do I compare user input with json data? @V.Sambor

Comment: @KarimZ I've answered, please check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is not good: `if (input === data[country]) {`

you have to check with the same mechanism as you have checked for country above...

`let inputCountry = data.find(check => check.country === input);`

Like this:

```js
const data = [{"country":"USA","active":true},
{"country":"Spain","active":true},
{"country":"Norway","active":true}];


document.getElementById("check").addEventListener("click", checkCountry);
  
  
function checkCountry() {
    let input = document.getElementById("countryInput").value;
    let country = data.find(check => check.country === "Norway");
    let inputCountry = data.find(check => check.country === input);
    let text;

    // You have to check with the country
    if (inputCountry && input === inputCountry.country) {
      text = "Yes";

    } else {
      text = "No";
    }
    console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
 <div class="input-container">
  <input id="countryInput" type="text" placeholder="Country">
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
 </div>  
  <button id="check" type="button">CHECK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What about if the user searches for other countries than Norway? Because I have a json file with 50 countries.

Comment: Check it now please

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `data[country]` because `data` isn't key value pair collection.
It consists of objects.
Try to change resulting json from `{'country': 'Spain', 'active': true}, ...` to 
`'Spain': {active: true}, ...`
Or call data element via:

```
if (input === data.find(el => el.country == country)) {
  text = "Yes";

} else {
  text = "No";
}
```